# Puppeteer HTML to PDF is not applying external css files

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using `Puppeteer` in node.js to convert an `html` string to a `pdf` file. Styles inside the `head` are working but those linked from local `.css` files with absolute path are not. Here is the code:

```
createPDF: async (html, file) => {
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: true
     })
     const page = await browser.newPage()
     await page.setContent(html, {
          waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
     })
     await page.pdf({
          format: 'A4',
          path: file,
          printBackground: true
     })
     await browser.close()
}
```

The `head` of the `html` looks like this:

```
<link href="C:\dev\project\src\views\tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
     .maindiv{
          padding-top:15pt;
     }
</style>
```

I also tried using a `url` instead but nothing changed.

Comment: That `href` shouldn't work in a browser either; either use a relative path or prepend `file:///`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you've already solved the above issue. I had the same issue when including a JS file into the HTML template. I solved the issue by adding `await page.addScriptTag({path: './ej2.min.js'})` before `page.setContent()`. No need to add the script tag to the HTML page. To include style file following method `addStyleTag('file-name-goes-here')` can be use. For the file path use the relative path from the base project directory.

Comment: What is this ej2.min.js file and where is it coming from?
Adding this snippet to my code results in an error that the file cannot be found.

Is this solution working?

Comment: That file was a JS file that I wanted to import to the HTML page. I included that file inside the same directory and imported using the above line

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for css/js dependencies to load first seem to solve it.

```
await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'load' });
```

Answer (score 0):

When generating PDFs with Puppeteer, background colors and images are not included in the PDF by default due to browser print settings designed to save ink/toner. However, you can easily include background colors in your PDFs by setting the `printBackground` option to `true` in the `page.pdf()` method options.

Here's how you can do it:

```js
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
  format: "A4",
  printBackground: true // This ensures background colors are printed
});
```

Adding `printBackground: true` instructs Puppeteer to capture and include the background color (and images) in the PDF. This is particularly useful when your document's visual presentation is crucial, and you need to maintain fidelity to the web version.

Ensure this option is set anytime you require the background to be part of your PDF output, such as when generating invoices, reports, or any document where CSS plays a significant role in the layout and presentation.

If you're still not seeing the expected results, double-check your CSS to ensure the background is correctly applied. For complex layouts or when using external stylesheets, make sure Puppeteer loads all resources before generating the PDF. For direct content setting with `setContent`, incorporating all styles inline or embedded within the HTML content is recommended to avoid missing styles.

This solution is straightforward and effective for including background colors in PDFs generated with Puppeteer, ensuring your documents look as intended.